# WSL2 Failed install docker desktop on Windows 11

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

When I use the win11 version and use wsl2 to distribute Docker Desktop 4.16.3,
Error prompt encountered during startup
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNYMN.png)
`Docker failed to initialize Docker Desktop is shutting down`

`Docker.Core.HttpBadResponseException: {"message":"2 errors occurred:\n\t* provisioning docker WSL distros: deploying \"docker-desktop\": importing WSL distro \"docker-desktop\": deploying WSL distro \"docker-desktop\" (\"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Docker\\\\Docker\\\\resources\\\\wsl\\\\wsl-bootstrap.tar\" -\u003e \"C:\\\\Users\\\\15208\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Docker\\\\wsl\\\\distro\"): exit status 0xffffffff\n\t* checking if isocache exists: CreateFile \\\\wsl$\\docker-desktop-data\\isocache\\: The network name cannot be found.\n\n"}`

I try to change the version

Update system

set wsl default version

wsl --upate； wsl --shutdown

There is no way to solve it

Answer (score 2):

you could run `wsl --update` then on the cmd as admin `netsh winsock reset`
then restart the machine worked for me